# How are the Proverbs in the Proverbs book organized? By author? Theme? Chronologically?

Tags: proverbs, literary-structure

I would love to know if the book is compiled in any specific manner. It follows a theme order it seems, but is that intended by the authors, or some were organized later on and placed in some kind of way to facilitate our reading?

Answer (score 1):

As one author states it: http://www.messiah-study.net/proverbs-themes.htm

> When one reads through the book of Proverbs, the general impression is
> that the book consists of many free-standing, unrelated thoughts. It
> is as if someone picked up pebbles and shells on the beach and put
> them all mixed up into one bag.

The next link gives an extensive **(A)** outline, and further down the page is a **(B)** list of verses of Proverbs by topic.  https://community.logos.com/forums/t/49361.aspx

**(A)** **The Outline Bible**: (excerpt)

SECTION OUTLINE ONE (PROVERBS 1)

Wisdom warns about being enticed by sinners.

I.      THE REASONS FOR THE PROVERBS (1:1–7)

```
A.      To grasp wisdom and discipline (1:1–2): They help with the understanding of wise sayings.

B.      To receive guidance and understand deep thoughts (1:3, 5–7): People who listen to the proverbs learn the fear of the Lord.

C.      To give insight to the immature and mature alike (1:4) : The Proverbs give knowledge and purpose.
```

II.      THE RECIPIENTS OF THE PROVERBS (1:8–33): Solomon’s son in particular

```
A.      Advice regarding wicked companions (1:8–19): Stay away from them! Why?

  1.      They terrorize others (1:8–17).

  2.      They trap themselves and rob themselves of life (1:18–19).

B.      Advice regarding wisdom’s counsel (1:20–33): Stay close to her!

  1.      Her call (1:20–21): She shouts out in the streets.

  2.      Her condemnation (1:22–32): She calls; fools do not listen or come to her.

  3.      Her consolation (1:33) : All who listen to her live in peace and safety.
```

**(B)** List of Verses by Topic (excerpt):

> Anger - Prov 12:16; 14:17; 14:29; 15:1; 15:18; 16:32; 19:3; 19:11;
> 19:19; 20:2; 21:14; 22:24–25; 29:22
>
> Children - Prov 10:1; 13:1; 13:24; 14:26; 15:20; 17:6; 17:21; 17:25;
> 19:13; 19:18; 19:26; 20:11; 20:20; 22:6; 22:15; 23:13–14; 23:22–25;
> 28:7; 28:24; 29:15; 29:17
>
> Contentment - Prov 13:25; 14:30; 16:8; 19:23; 23:4–5; 25:16; 30:15–16
>
> Courage - Prov 24:10–12; 25:26; 28:1
>
> Debt - Prov 6:1–5; 17:18; 20:16; 22:7; 22:26–27; 27:13
>
> Dishonesty - Prov 6:16–19; 10:18; 11:1; 12:17; 12:19; 12:22; 13:5;
> 14:5; 14:25; 16:28; 16:30; 17:7; 17:20; 19:5; 19:9; 19:22; 20:10;
> 20:14; 20:17; 20:23; 21:6; 21:28; 24:28–29; 25:14; 25:18; 26:18–19;
> 26:23–28; 29:12; 30:8

For a detailed look at Proverbs, there is Bullinger's (*The Companion Bible*) Appendixes 74 and 75:  https://levendwater.org/companion/index_companion.html

74. The Book of Proverbs: Introduction and Analysis
75. Special Passages in the Book of Proverbs acquiring New Light